# Marketing Cloud permissions in Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, permissions

Hi I'm trying to setup a customize role in marketing cloud?

What are the restrictions is needed for not showing a data extension record in email studio and Contact builder?

Comment: Marketing Cloud doesn't support row level security

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible, there are no granular permissions for DE based on role/user

There are a few ideas you could upvote:

[Folder permissions in Marketing Cloud by role or user](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TtG1QAK)
[Configuration option for access permission on individual folders/entities](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000PZ6oQAG)
[Allow Roles to Separate Access between Sensitive Client Data & Test QA Data](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003df3QAA)
[Configure Permissions for Data Extensions in Same Business Unit](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000UJu0QAG)